# Method can't be read from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable gem. I am an error:

> NoMethodError in PostsController#index
>   -  undefined method `upvote_post_path' for #<#:0x007fb5010f34b8>

Basically what I did is put a link for specific task in my view.

```
  <%= link_to "upvote", upvote_post_path(post), method: put %>
```

Similar link:

```
<%= link_to "edit", edit_post_path(post)%>
```

inside the same view works just fine. Here is my controller part of these two methods:

```
  def destroy
    @post = current_post
    @post.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Post deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

  def upvote
    @post.liked_by current_user
  end
```

These are my routes:

```
  resources :users
  resources :posts do
    put 'upvote', to: 'posts#upvote'
  end
```

I am unable to figure out where is the issue.

Comment: what is your `rake routes` output?

Comment: @sureshprasanna70 I updated question with screenshot of rake routes output.

Comment: it should be post_upvote_path(post)

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that after reading rake routes output. Thanks! To whom among you two is fair to give green check for answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to route should have been 
`post_upvote_path(post)` instead `upvote_post_path(post)`

Answer (score 4):

Your call in View for `upvote_post_path` should be:

`post_upvote_path(post)` instead of `upvote_post_path(post)`

should look like this:

```
<%= link_to "upvote", post_upvote_path(post), method: put %>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per rake routes

```
 <%= link_to "upvote", post_upvote_path(post), method: put %>
```